# Difference between “Drohung”, “Bedrohung” and “Androhung”

Tags: difference, german-to-english

For my German translation needs, I use [Beolingus](http://dict.tu-chemnitz.de). I searched the translation for the word *Bedrohung,* which would mean *menace* or *threat,* but I see that *Androhung* and *Drohung* mean the same thing.

Is there a difference I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An "Androhung" or "Drohung" requires that you can assume an *intentional stance* towards the threatening agent - a mobster threatening to smash up your store, or a government issuing an ultimatum. These things are are always delivered explicitly, usually via words (although a raised fist may suffice). A typical "Androhung":

> Morgen wirst du verprügelt!

A "Bedrohung" *can* (but doesn't have to) be entirely circumstantial: a settlement may be threatened by plundering bandits whether they announce themselves or not, and it can even be threatened by extreme cold. A typical "Bedrohung" is that of atomic energy, which people fear both because an accident might pollute an entire province, *and* because nuclear war might destroy entire continents.

Comment: *Androhen* benötigt ein Akkusativobjekt, daher sollte auch *Androhung* nicht alleine stehen. Eine Androhung von Prügel ist eine Drohung.